# Password HTML redirect

Tags: html

Points:
I dont mind if users can see it using - view source.
I don't really know much about this but I really want to get this working.

I need to add a password to this somehow, I need it so that if a person enters "hello" it will redirect, if anything else is entered nothing happens.

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <form class="form1" action="http://google.com">

        <div class="formtitle">Enter the password to proceed</div>

        <div class="input nobottomborder">
            <div class="inputtext">Password: </div>
            <div class="inputcontent">

                <input type="password" />
                <br/>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">

            <input class="orangebutton" type="submit" value="Login" />


        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You know that you can read HTML in the source? So users can open the source and see what they have to type in there?

Comment: You should try a little research, as the answer is not that hard to find

Comment: I have a way around this, but first I need it to be done.

Comment: The answer is really hard to find :P thats why I'm here :)

Comment: HTML can't do it (it can provide a way for the user to send input somewhere, but that is all). You need a programming language to write a program to do it, and that needs to run on the server if it is to be anything other than a joke. Pick a programming language and read up on how to use it with your web server.

Comment: Like, I would like the password to be inside of the code. Its okay if users can see it using view-source.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that with redirect you mean to allow the form to submit,

give a name to your password field

```
<input type="password" name="pass" />
```

and change

```
<form class="form1" action="http://google.com">
```

to

```
<form class="form1" action="http://google.com" onsubmit="return (this.pass.value==='hello')?true:false;">
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/nCfQ4/1/

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at onsumbit:

```
<form class="form1" action="http://google.com" onsubmit="return document.getElementById('password').value=='hello';">
....
    <input type="password" id="password"/>
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you have a number of options but the best in my view is PHP, you could use JS but people will be able to read the code.

PHP with the POST for the method then access a database etc.

Comment: I understand, but I just need what I already have modified to put in a password.

Comment: Ah, [PHP](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/06/the-php-singularity.html)