# Password correct? then redirect

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Password HTML redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783646/password-html-redirect)

So I have this code and I need it to only redirect when the correct password is added. Only problem is that I dont know what to add that will make it only redirect if the password is "hello"
I understand that using "view-source" would reveal the password, I don't mind that, its the way I want it.
I basically just need to know what to add and where to add it.

Sooo:
Redirects if "hello" is typed into password field.
Does nothing if anything else is put into the password field.

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <form class="form1" action="http://google.com">

        <div class="formtitle">Enter the password to proceed</div>

        <div class="input nobottomborder">
            <div class="inputtext">Password: </div>
            <div class="inputcontent">

                <input type="password" />
                <br/>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">

            <input class="orangebutton" type="submit" value="Login" />


        </div>

</div>
```

I hope this was clear and could be understood.

UPDATED:
    
    
        
            Enter the password to proceed

```
    <div class="input nobottomborder">
        <div class="inputtext">
            Password:
        </div>

        <div class="inputcontent">
            <input type="password" id="password" /><br />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <input class="orangebutton" type="submit" value="Continue" onclick="if (document.getElementById('password').value == 'hello') location.href='members.html'; else alert('Wrong Password!');" />
    </div>
</form>
```

​

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use javascript. All you need is an event listener on the login button, then you check the value of the input field and redirect. This is simple enough to do it with plain javascript, but it's even easier with jQuery.
It should be something like this (but I haven't test the code).

```
$('.orangebutton').click(function () {
    if ($('input:password').val() == "hello") {
        window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    }
});
```

Of course you have to include jquery library and make sure that the dom is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

#### Explanation

The code which I have used here is:

```
if (document.getElementById('password').value == 'hello')
    alert('Correct Password!');
else
    alert('Wrong Password!');
```

Now for your question, we can replace the `alert('Correct Password!');` with `location.href='members.html'` or something.

```
if (document.getElementById('password').value == 'hello')
    location.href='members.html';
else
    alert('Wrong Password!');
```

#### Check this out. Not used jQuery, it is pure JavaScript

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <form class="form1" action="http://google.com">
        <div class="formtitle">
            Enter the password to proceed
        </div>

        <div class="input nobottomborder">
            <div class="inputtext">
                Password:
            </div>

            <div class="inputcontent">
                <input type="password" id="password" /><br />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <input class="orangebutton" type="submit" value="Login" onclick="if (document.getElementById('password').value == 'hello') alert('Correct Password!'); else alert('Wrong Password!');" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>​
```

#### Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AmMwQ/

Comment: This is great! only one problem the location.href='members.html' does not work. when i get the password correct, it does not redirect.

Comment: Can you post the full code in your question? Edit it and update.

Comment: Check this out in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/AmMwQ/1/

Comment: I have also tried window.location.href='members.html';

Comment: I added an update to the question

Comment: Also I don't have any browsers besides Google Chrome, thats what iim using

Comment: Actually this should work. Gimme a second, will fix it out. :)

Comment: There is an issue with Google Chrome: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/rJ-3XA8rOQ4

Comment: Try, `window.location='http://www.google.com/'` or all the three combinations. See which is working for you. For me, in Chrome developer tools, everything is getting working.

Comment: I just tried it on internet explorer, not working

Comment: What are all the combinations? I tried the one you gave me now window.location='http://www.google.com/' that does not work ether.

Comment: `window.location='http://www.google.com/'`, `window.location.href='http://www.google.com/'`, `location.href='http://www.google.com/'`