# Redirect Issue With Code

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Password HTML redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783646/password-html-redirect)

I'm having some problems with the code below, specifically `window.location="http://www.google.com"` I can't get it to redirect when I enter the correct password.

```
    <div class="buttons">
        <input class="orangebutton" type="submit" value="Continue" onclick="if (document.getElementById('password').value == 'hi') window.location="http://www.google.com" else alert('Wrong Password!');" />
    </div>
```

UPDATE:
This is what I have now, the redirect is still not working.

```
        <input class="orangebutton" type="submit" value="Continue" onclick="if (document.getElementById('password').value == 'hello') window.location='http://www.google.com'; else alert('Wrong Password!');" />
```

Comment: Use single quotes for `http://www.google.com`. Another observation is that people could easily know what the password is...

Comment: Having a password check visible in the source for the page? Awesome.

Comment: @TheZ, Surely this is example code, and not what will actually be implemented.

Comment: @Brad If it's any kind of javascript check (besides perhaps node.js since that's server-side or an ajax call for validation), it's visible to the world with minimal effort.

Comment: @TheZ, Oh, I don't disagree at all.  I'm just saying that this is probably just test code, and he isn't actually doing a client-side password check.  Of course, I could be wrong...

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape double quotes, also better to use the `.href` property which is a string, rather the `location` alone which is an object, like so:

```
window.location.href='http://www.google.com'
```

**UPDATE:**
Use single-quotes instead of double-quotes as the later can't escape in the context of an html element. Thanks to James Beilby for spotting this.

Comment: Escaping double quotes would work in the context of a Javascript string but not here: the OP needs to use single quotes.

Comment: I don't think so James, try a jsfiddle for you to see.

Comment: Hmm, just tried one and seems to need single quotes in IE and Firefox. Again this is in the context of an event handler in the HTML body, rather than a Javascript variable.

Comment: I eat my own words, you were right, updating my answer accordingly, thanks!

Comment: No problem, I only know from making this mistake often enough!

Answer (score 2):

I can't be sure this is the only issue without more details, but you are using double quotes in:

```
window.location="http://www.google.com"
```

Since you are using double quotes to encapsulate the entire onclick statement, you will need to use single quotes instead:

```
window.location='http://www.google.com'
```

Additionally, you will need a semi-colon before the keyword "else". The entire handler becomes:

```
onclick="if (document.getElementById('password').value == 'hi') window.location='http://www.google.com'; else alert('Wrong Password!');"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two error in your code:

1) value of `onclick` parameter includes `"` and string ends at that point.  Use `'` (single quote) instead.

2) there should be `;` just before `else` keyword.

So, finally it should be `window.location='http://www.google.com';`

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your syntax. You should not use `"` inside the `onclick=""`. So replace it with:

```
<input class="orangebutton" type="submit" value="Continue"
       onclick="if (document.getElementById('password').value == 'hi') window.location='http://www.google.com' else alert('Wrong Password!');" />
```

Comment: Things are not working out well for me, I updated the post.